# Default project setup adds "java" folder

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I tried to setup a web application on Netbeans 7.2.1. A "java" folder is added under "src" folder. If java folder is deleted and  folder below java folder "com" is moved up the hierarchy then Source Packages do not reflect in project view.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `java` folder? Why fight a regularly used code organization?

Comment: When other web apps are imported , I dont get to see java folder. My concern is currently building new application and am running into classpath resolving issues. It may or may not be related to "java" folder but would like to rule out "java" folder as the cause.